# How to get the x and y axis on click Angular JS Charts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am trying to get the values for x and y axis for onclick on the chart area. As for now I am doing :

html :

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.2"></script>
<script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.3.11" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.11/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/bower/dist/angular-charts.min.js"></script>

<div ac-chart="'area'" ac-data="barData" ac-config="config" id='chart2' class='chart'  style="width: 100%"></div>
```

JS :

```
$scope.config = {
                        title: 'Customer Distribution',
                        tooltips: true,
                        labels: false,
                        mouseover: function () {
                        },
                        mouseout: function () {
                        },
                        click: function (d) {
                            console.log(d);
                            console.log(angular.toJson(d));
                        },
                        isAnimate: true,
                        waitForHeightAndWidth: false,
                        legend: {
                            display: true,
                            //could be 'left, right'
                            position: 'right',
                            htmlEnabled: false

                        }
                    };


                    var sin = [];

                    if (angular.equals(bin, "UNIT")) {
                        angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
                            var y = [];
                            y.push(item.customerListSize);
                            sin.push({x: item.value, y: y});
                        });
                    } else {
                        angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
                            var y = [];
                            y.push(item.totalBinSize);
                            sin.push({x: item.binName, y: y});
                        });
                    }

                    $scope.barData = {
                        series: [featureType],
                        data: sin
                    };
```

The charts showing up properly but I want to add some functionality on click ? I need to get the x and y values of the chart when clicked so that I can add it to tool tip also call other method with that value. Can some one tell me how do I get the values on click. I tried printing the console when clicking it just shows the screen position.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
click: function(d) {
  console.log(d);
},
```

`d` will the the `datum` of the object clicked on.

Comment: @user3407267, you are correct, my apologies.  Did you want the x, y positions of the `click` for the x,y values of the thing that's clicked?